# ¿Como llamar una api en xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

Como puedo llamar a mi api que esta creada desde php en xamarin

```
function obtenerTodosLosClientes(){
        try{
            $conexion = conectar();
            $cadena = "select * from clientes;";
            $result = $conexion->query($cadena);
            $resultArray = array();
            foreach($result as $registros){
                $resultArray[] = $registros;
            }
            
        }catch(Exception $e){
            
        }
        return convertirUTF8($resultArray);
    }
```

Este es mi codigo de la api, lo devuelvo convertido en json

```
[
  {
    "cedula": "1",
    "nombres": "a",
    "apellidos": "a",
    "direccion": "a",
    "celular": "a",
    "estado": "0"
  }
]
```

Asi llega

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.0.23/practicaPhp/SuegraJhon/api/obtenerRegistros");
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<Cliente>>(response);
            Lista_Deudores.ItemsSource = result;
```

Y asi intento llamarla desde un boton para que me llene una lista pero cuando la intento clickear el boton me da error porque la peticion que hago me trae todo el html no solo el json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cuando haces la consulta desde la web, te muestra el json?

Answer (score 0):

Te falta leer el contenido como un string usando GetAsync para poder usar la respuesta y saber si fue buena o no, luego deserializar.

te falta tambien controlar que tenga contenido y que la respuesta sea ok como minimo sino esta lista para romper esta llamada.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.0.23/practicaPhp/SuegraJhon/api/obtenerRegistros");

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            if (response.Content != null)
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cliente>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                Lista_Deudores.ItemsSource = result;
            }
        }
```